# Values from vanilla JavaScript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to know how to send something to php using ajax and vanilla javascript.
I ask you because I just found jQuery solution.

I know that if I want to recieve something it should looks like this:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      this.responseText; // This is my response
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "phpfile.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Someone can explain or send me to solution because I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest) something like what you're looking for?

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45529553/2397327) is very intriguing and uses a simple, modern syntax (but perhaps not compatible with all browsers)

Comment: `xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        http.send(JSON.stringify(params))`

These are the two lines I need?
In `params` Can I just write some variables after `,`?

Comment: It's worth a try!

Comment: What is the second argument of setRequestHeader?

Comment: I'm assuming it's the [MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) type of the data, which the receiving end can use to determine what kind of data it's receiving.

Comment: Thank you and now I have to recieve this in PHP using `json_decode()`? If so, how should it look more or less?

Comment: Exactly! I'll write up a quick answer demonstrating how to use `JSON.stringify()` and `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 3):

**First method**

To send data from JavaScript to PHP (or any other script) should be just as you found out:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

where `params` is some JavaScript variable. `application/json` is the datatype for JSON data.

On the PHP side, you were also correct: use `JSON_decode()` to get a PHP-equivalent to the JavaScript data you sent.

---

**Second method** (only for GET requests)

GET data is encoded in the URL, so an alternative way is to encode the data directly into the URL of the PHP script. (Don't do this for sensitive data.)

Javascript:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "phpfile.php?x=2&y=3&z=4");
```

PHP:

```
$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];
$z = $_GET["z"];
```

---

Because you seemed unclear on how to send multiple variables using the first method:

If you want to send multiple variables, put it into an object or array (because `JSON.stringify()` only takes one (data) argument, not a comma-separated list of arguments).

```
// for example, to send the variables x, y, z
var xValue = 2;
var yValue = 3;
var zValue = 4;
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ x: xValue, y: yValue, z: zValue }));
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_GET);
echo $data->x;  // 2
echo $data->y;  // 3
echo $data->z;  // 4;
```

(disclaimer: code is untested; I'm not sure if data is received into the `$_GET` variable. Use `json_decode()` on the variable that PHP receives JSON data from.)

Comment: I will try it later now I need to go. You explained it as if I wanted it. Thank you so much :)
There is a mistake. I am sorry for that.
`http.send(JSON.stringify(params));`
.
`xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(params));`